# ZonedDateTime -> ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(zd1(Hour 2), zd2(Hour 1)) return -2

Tags: java-8, dst, java-time, date-difference, zoneddatetime

I am trying to understand why is it that the result of the code is -2, initially I thought it should be -1, but this one really puzzled me

```
LocalDateTime ld1 = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.NOVEMBER, 1, 2, 0);
ZonedDateTime zd1 = ZonedDateTime.of(ld1, ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));
LocalDateTime ld2 = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.NOVEMBER, 1, 1, 0);
ZonedDateTime zd2 = ZonedDateTime.of(ld2, ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));
long x = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(zd1, zd2);
System.out.println(x);
```

output : -2

```
LocalDateTime ld1 = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.NOVEMBER, 1, 3, 0);
ZonedDateTime zd1 = ZonedDateTime.of(ld1, ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));
LocalDateTime ld2 = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.NOVEMBER, 1, 2, 0);
ZonedDateTime zd2 = ZonedDateTime.of(ld2, ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));
long x = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(zd1, zd2);
System.out.println(x);
```

Below are the examples which results works as I expected!

output : -1

```
LocalDateTime ld1 = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.NOVEMBER, 1, 2, 0);
ZonedDateTime zd1 = ZonedDateTime.of(ld1, ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));
LocalDateTime ld2 = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.NOVEMBER, 1, 3, 0);
ZonedDateTime zd2 = ZonedDateTime.of(ld2, ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));
long x = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(zd1, zd2);
System.out.println(x);
```

output : 1

If someone can help me understand this better, really appreciated.

Comment: How can you get `1` from the third example when it's *exactly* the same as the second example?

Comment: With a microscopic amount of **research**, i.e. printing the values of `zd1` and `zd2`, you'd have know the answer.

Comment: That's Daylight Saving Time: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york - clocks shift back 1 hour, so 2 hours has passed between them. You can check this by verifying the corresponding instant of each date: `zd1.toInstant()` will give you the UTC instant, you'll see that the difference is 2 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`US/Eastern`, in [IANA database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) (the source where those names come from) is the same as `America/New_York` timezone (check [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to check the equivalence - search for `US/Eastern`).

And in `America/New_York` timezone, [Daylight Saving Time ended at November 1<sup>st</sup> 2015](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/new-york?year=2015): at 2 AM, clocks shift back 1 hour to 1 AM, and offset changed from `-04:00` to `-05:00`.

If you check the `ZonedDateTime`'s, you'll see the offset change:

```
System.out.println(zd1);
System.out.println(zd2);
```

The output is:

> 2015-11-01T02:00-05:00[US/Eastern]
>   2015-11-01T01:00-04:00[US/Eastern]

If you see the corresponding `Instant`, you'll see both dates in UTC:

```
System.out.println(zd1.toInstant());
System.out.println(zd2.toInstant());
```

> 2015-11-01T07:00:00Z
>   2015-11-01T05:00:00Z

Note that the difference between those dates is 2 hours. You can check this by adding 1 and 2 hours to `zd2`:

```
System.out.println(zd2);
System.out.println(zd2.plusHours(1));
System.out.println(zd2.plusHours(2));
```

The output is:

> 2015-11-01T01:00-04:00[US/Eastern]
>   2015-11-01T01:00-05:00[US/Eastern]
>   2015-11-01T02:00-05:00[US/Eastern]

So, starting at 1 AM in offset `-04:00`, 1 hour later you are at 2 AM in offset `-04:00`, but due to DST change, clocks shift back to 1 AM in offset `-05:00`. Then, 1 hour later, you're at 2 AM in offset `05:00` (`zd1`). That's why the difference is 2 hours.

This doesn't happen in your second test, because both dates are in the same offset (`-05:00`), after DST change occurred. So, the difference is just 1 hour. You can again check this by printing the dates and the corresponding `Instant`:

```
LocalDateTime ld1 = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.NOVEMBER, 1, 2, 0);
ZonedDateTime zd1 = ZonedDateTime.of(ld1, ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));
LocalDateTime ld2 = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.NOVEMBER, 1, 3, 0);
ZonedDateTime zd2 = ZonedDateTime.of(ld2, ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));
System.out.println(zd1);
System.out.println(zd2);
System.out.println(zd1.toInstant());
System.out.println(zd2.toInstant());
```

> 2015-11-01T02:00-05:00[US/Eastern]
>   2015-11-01T03:00-05:00[US/Eastern]
>   2015-11-01T07:00:00Z
>   2015-11-01T08:00:00Z

Note that the offset is the same, and by the corresponding UTC `Instant` we can see that the difference is only 1 hour.

Answer (score 2):

When you look at the `ZonedDateTime` objects, you see these:

```
zd1 = '2015-11-01T02:00-05:00[US/Eastern]'
zd2 = '2015-11-01T01:00-04:00[US/Eastern]'
```

Daylight Savings Time ended on 1 November 2015. 1am occurred before the clocks went back, and 2am occurred after the clocks went back.  Thus two hours difference.